# Deprecation of recordingDetails.location in YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It appears that as of June 1, 2017 [the following video resource properties are being deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_06_01_2017):

```
recordingDetails.locationDescription
recordingDetails.location.latitude
recordingDetails.location.longitude
```

The annoying part is that I can't find a replacement. Is there a chance that someone is more lucky searching for these?

Answer (score 2):

You can't find any as the docs in the [Revision History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_06_01_2017) didn't mention any replacement. This isn't the first time a feature/property has been deprecated or cut off. You can see others in a [deprecated list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/deprecated).

Check the [Youtube Engineering and Developers Blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/) if a new update comes along.

Comment: Uuh what a bummer. I was fighting (java)locationdetail but failed.  All I can put is `recordingdetails.setRecordingDate` value. Publishing videos from the standalone application need this, no one is manually going through videos to edit values in studio.youtube.com editor. Sad.